# PostgreSQL - Syntax Error When Creating Function With If ELSIF Statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Could someone help explain what's wrong with syntax for the following codes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION linearly_decrement_offset(location_in text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$BEGIN

IF tempoffset.ts_insert <= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '15 minutes':: interval AND tempoffset.ts_insert > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes':: interval THEN
    UPDATE tempoffset
        SET offset_factor = offset_factor * 0.75
        WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
ELSIF tempoffset.ts_insert =< (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes'::interval AND tempoffset.ts_insert > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval THEN
    UPDATE tempoffset
        SET offset_factor = offset_factor* 0.5
        WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
ELSIF tempoffset.ts_insert =< (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval AND tempoffset.ts_inset > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '1 hour'::interval THEN
    UPDATE tempoffset
        SET offset_factor = offset_factor * 0.25
        WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
ELSIF tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '1 hour'::interval THEN
    DELETE FROM tempoffset;
END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION linearly_decrement_offset(text)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I got the following error when tried to execute it.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 3:  IF tempoffset.ts_insert <= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '15...
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 9
```

Comment: Just a note, you could probably simplify this using something like `1 - width_bucket(...)*0.25`. [`width_bucket` doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html). Also not quite sure why you want to store this in a temp table instead of calculating on the fly.

Comment: Plase show the **full** `create function` statement.

Comment: You can't use the column of a table in an IF statement like that. To which row would that belong to? You need to run a `select` query to retrieve data from a table. Although this looks like as if the you don't need an IF at all. This could probably be done in a single update statement (apart from the `delete`). What exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am trying to linearly decrease the `offset_factor` value from `tempoffset`  table. So, for example decrease the `offset_factor` value by 25% if the existing values are 15 minutes and older but less than 30 mintues from the current query, and so on. I am trying to implement a REST API for an iOS app.

Comment: Is this something that really needs to be done server side? Are you using this for something server side or is the client actually fetching it? If the client is actually fetching it directly, you could save yourself the network overhead by doing it client side. Even server side, if it's not something you need in database, you could save yourself the overhead of fetching from the DB by calculating in the app code.

Comment: @jpmc26 The front end guy told me to do it on Server Side, I have no experience developing iOS app. This is used in an iOS app, not for server side.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm being an idiot and missing details. Forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a table column like that in an `if` statement. You need to first retrieve the value of a row using `select .. into` and store it in a local variable. Then you can compare the values.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION linearly_decrement_offset(location_in text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
   l_insert_ts timestamp;  --- a local variable to hold the value
BEGIN

   -- this select assumes that location_in is unique 
   -- (and thus the select returns exactly one row)
   -- otherwise the select .. into will throw an error
   select ts_insert
      into l_insert_ts
   from tempoffset
   WHERE location = location_in;

    IF l_insert_ts <= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '15 minutes'::interval AND l_insert_ts > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes'::interval THEN
        UPDATE tempoffset
            SET offset_factor = offset_factor * 0.75
            WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
    ELSIF l_insert_ts <= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes'::interval AND l_insert_ts > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval THEN
        UPDATE tempoffset
            SET offset_factor = offset_factor* 0.5
            WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
    ELSIF l_insert_ts <= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval AND l_insert_ts > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '1 hour'::interval THEN
        UPDATE tempoffset
            SET offset_factor = offset_factor * 0.25
            WHERE tempoffset.location = location_in;
    ELSIF tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '1 hour'::interval THEN
        DELETE FROM tempoffset;
    END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: @SaiWaiMaung then you need to take a step back and define the problem you're trying to solve better. The problem isn't just a syntax error. Describe what you're actually trying to do, what the data is, how you're trying to transform it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want to apply to the entire table tempoffset?  I am probably missing something, but, as a_horse_with_no_name said, you could probably do this with an update followed by a delete, something like:

```
$BODY$
BEGIN

update tempoffset
set offset_factor = offset_factor *
   when tempoffset.ts_insert >= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '15 minutes'::interval
    AND tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes'::interval) then 0.75
   when tempoffset.ts_insert >= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '30 minutes'::interval
    AND tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval) then 0.50
   when tempoffset.ts_insert >= (now() at time zone 'utc') - '45 minutes'::interval
    AND tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '60 minutes'::interval) then 0.25;

delete from tempoffset where tempoffset.ts_insert < (now() at time zone 'utc') - '15 minutes'::interval or
            tempoffset.ts_insert > (now() at time zone 'utc') - '60 minutes'::interval);


END;
$BODY$
```

Sorry, I didn't test it, I haven't used the when / then in a multiplication before.  But, this will update the tempoffset table by the appropriate factors, or if the time is not bracketed then the data will be deleted.  I felt like the <= > were bracketing backwards, but, maybe I got that wrong.

-g

Comment: Yes, I want to apply to the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between the  '15 minutes':: interval  in the if statement.

Comment: The space between :: and interval.

Comment: I just want to verify that you realize that in your comment you have no space between the ::interval.  However the code you supplied has a space on the 15 minute line and the others do not.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that because you didn't format the example as `code`. But still: the space doesn't make a difference. `'15 minutes':: interval'` works just as fine as `'15 minutes'::interval`

Comment: try switching the first <= to =<

Comment: That's wrong as well. the "lower or equal" operator in SQL and PL/pgSQL is `<=` not `=<`